# Need to separate shell Command output in Row and Column

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csv, scripting

I have below script which is perfectly working fine for me. The only problem i am facing that the output is going in ".csv" format, but when i download those .csv file in excel i can see all the data in one row only.

Can any one please help me to correct the changes if i can do then can see the output even if i open in excel it should show in row and column.

```
#!/bin/sh

ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
date=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ifile="$(date '+/var/tmp/EndpointUsage_%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y.csv')"
"$ipath"/cli iedge list | awk '
BEGIN { print "|-----------------|------------------|";
printf "|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n","Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"
}
/Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
/Ongoing Calls/ {print "|-------------------|-----------------|"; printf          
"|%-17s|%-16s|\r\n",id,$3 }
END{
print "|------------------|------------------|";
}'>> "$ifile"
```

Output on on server i can see like below, which is pretty much ok on CLI, but when i open those files in excel it is giving everything in single row

```
------------------------------------
|Registration ID  |Ongoing Calls   |
------------------------------------
|NITIN_03|30                       |
------------------------------------
|NITIN_01|0                        |
------------------------------------
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use the 'Data' tab on the ribbon, click on the 'Text-to-Columns' and then follow the wizard. select '|' as the field seperator. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter can you please advise where to put '|" this in script.

Comment: I think the script looks OK. Maybe you want to make the separator lines look like `|----------|------------|` . Maybe you need to change all references of `\n` to \r\n` in your print statements. That will make your file more Windows friendly, but I don't recall ever doing that on the projects that I've worked on. So I think the most likely problem is related to the 'Text-To-Columns' feature as mentioned above. Have you tried what I recommend? Maybe you'll have to update your question with a **small** screen capture from excel to show your specific problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter i tried about separator what you recommended but doesn't not change anything. Please check the script about after the separator addition.

Comment: @shelter also what you suggested earlier to go in Text-to-column that is the function of Excel, i dont want that..i want to have the data which script can do.

Comment: We need to see what the output from `"$ipath"/cli iedge list` looks like before it goes into awk, so maybe capture that to a file, and then edit 2-3 records into the script, like `{ echo "rec 1 ..... " ; echo "rec 2 ...." ; echo "rec 3 ...." ; } | awk` ... so we can run code for ourselves.

Comment: I have been using excel for a long time importing Unix files. There used to be a time where what you ask for was not a problem. With the addition of the Ribbon and the Data->Text-to-Column "feature", you only get what ever import setup was last used (or default) and you MUST use text-to-Column. This will probably require reworking the way you load data into Excel and means that you have to have an vbs script to set the text-to-Column as part of the loading process. I'll be happy for proved wrong by other readers! as I hate this too. Please try using Text2Col and see if you can at least load.

Comment: Another (very painful) avenue to research, would be to find correct XML format used by Excel and then write your data as a native `.xlsx` file. I know that `perl` has had libraries for years now that can do that sort of thing. It might not be too bad. If you go that route, best to post a new question with `perl` tags. Good luck.